# Syntax Error on if-statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to output different text depending on the custom post type and I'm getting a syntax error which I believe is due to multiple if-statements. The problem is that I have a very limited knowledge of PHP. Any ideas?

```
<?php

if ( 'lettering' == get_post_type() ) {

    <?php if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) { 
            $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
            $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
            if( $total_attachments ) : ?>
            <ul id="process"><span>Process:</span>
            </ul>
            <br>
                <?php endif; ?> <?php } ?>

} elseif ( 'type' == get_post_type() ) {

    <?php if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) { 
            $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
            $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
            if( $total_attachments ) : ?>
            <ul id="process"><span>Additional Shots</span>
            </ul>
            <br>
                <?php endif; ?> <?php } ?>
}

?>
```

Comment: To put it bluntly, you're popping in/out of PHP mode like a drunken sailor on day 9 of a one-day pass. `<?php endif; ?><?php } ?>`? Why not just `<?php endif; } ?>`. plus, mixing alternate with regular syntax just makes for a reading nightmare.

Comment: Mixing alternate with regular syntax? Like I stated above, I have very limited knowledge of PHP. Care to explain?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove opening php tags like:
change:

```
<?php if ( 'lettering' == get_post_type() ) {

    this one --> <?php if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) {
```

to

```
<?php if ( 'lettering' == get_post_type() ) {

    if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) { 
      .......
```

and similarly in `elseif`

Added:

```
<?php
if ( 'lettering' == get_post_type() ) {
    if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) { 
        $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
        $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
        if( $total_attachments ): 
?>
                <ul id="process"><span>Process:</span>
                </ul>
                <br>
<?php 
        endif; 
    }
} else if ( 'type' == get_post_type() ) {
    if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) { 
        $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
        $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
        if( $total_attachments ): 
?>
                <ul id="process"><span>Additional Shots</span>
                </ul>
                <br>
<?php 
        endif;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error (unexpected T_ENDIF - line 36) which is the last endif;. Is this correct? http://pastebin.com/f6UGnyAw

Comment: Never used endif myself  (I find it better to just use {,}), but can it be that you get the error because you are using "endif;" AND "}" ?
At least from what I've seen you use both to end the same if .

Comment: the script you're posting is only 24 lines long in total - so don't know how you're getting an error on line 36, unless you're not showing all of the script

Comment: Wow. Indenting the code made this so much easier to understand. Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Comment: youre' welcome, yes indeed indenting code properly makes it really easier "the readability" of code to yourself and to others as well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As MarcB comments - popping in and out of PHP like this is not ideal. The alternative syntax is great if you are writing a predominantly HTML based file with some PHP injection, otherwise I'd use something like a HEREDOC to make things more easy to spot:

```
<?php

if ( 'lettering' == get_post_type() ) {
  if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) {
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments );

    if( $total_attachments ) {
      echo <<<EOSTRING

      <ul id="process"><span>Process:</span>
      </ul>
      <br>

EOSTRING
;
    }
  }
} elseif ( 'type' == get_post_type() ) {
  if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) {
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments );

    if( $total_attachments ) {
      echo <<<EOSTRING

      <ul id="process"><span>Additional Shots</span>
      </ul>
      <br>

EOSTRING
;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm... seems that the syntax highlighter doesn't like HEREDOCs